# Java octal calculations

Tags: java, octal

what is a recommended way to perform **addition** and **subtraction** operations on Octal numbers? (My search results to date have yielded only conversions of octals, but not how to perform arithmetic operations on actual octals).
My program would generate 2 octal values, then add or subtract these (randomly), and give the octal total.

eg.

```
 5 Octal + 3 Octal = 10 Octal;
 12 Octal - 3 Octal = 7 Octal;
```

I have tried using:

```
Integer.parseInt(int, 8),
```

but I am not clear on how to construct for the above results. I have the rest of the programming working, I'm just stuck on the octal calculations.
I am a brand new programming student, working my way through the "Art and Science of Java" textbook by Eric S. Roberts, and this is listed as a programming exercise (Chapter 7, Exercise 3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a basic misunderstanding of the concept.  Arithmetic is performed on *numbers*, not on *octal numbers* or *decimal numbers* or *hexadecimal numbers*.

The octal/decimal/hex aspect refers only to the written representation.

As you probably know, to write a literal octal value in the code, you prefix it with a leading zero.  Similarly to write a hex value you prefix it with `0x`.

To print a value in octal, use `Integer.toOctalString(int)`.

To parse a string and interpret it as an octal value, use `Integer.parseInt(value, radix)`, and specify `8` as the radix.

For example, you two examples become:

```
int value1 = Integer.parseInt("5", 8);
int value2 = Integer.parseInt("3", 8);

int result = value1 + value2;
System.out.println(Integer.toOctalString(result));
```

and

```
int value1 = Integer.parseInt("12", 8);
int value2 = Integer.parseInt("3", 8);

int result = value1 - value2;
System.out.println(Integer.toOctalString(result));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Integer.toOctalString(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toOctalString%28int%29) method to get octal representation of a number, if you meant that:

```
System.out.println(Integer.toOctalString(012 - 03));  // 7
System.out.println(Integer.toOctalString(05 + 03));   // 10
```